# Easy PHP SimpleXML Issue

Tags: php, simplexml

I've got a really bad brain block with this.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <fruits>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Banana</item>
  </fruits>
  <vegetables>
    <item>Lettuce</item>
    <item>Carrot</item>
  </vegetables>
</data>
```

I am tyring to use SimpleXML to retrieve an array containing "Apple, Orange, Banana". The code I am using is as follows:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('food.xml');

foreach($xml as $fruits=>$item) {
  $foodlist[] = $item;
}

print_r($foodlist); // Should display list of fruits.
```

But the list of fruits is not being stored to the array. What am I doing wrong?

Much thanks.

Comment: `print_r( $xml );` and print the results here please?

Comment: What exactly do you see?  Nothing?  Or just not what you expected?

Comment: hookedonwinter: I get `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [fruits] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => Apple [1] => Orange [2] => Banana ) ) [vegetables] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => Lettuce [1] => Carrot ) ) )`

Comment: Jonah: I get `Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => Apple [1] => Orange [2] => Banana ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => Lettuce [1] => Carrot ) ) )`, when what I want is just a list of the fruits in a simple array.

Comment: while you're using a var called $fruits, that doesn't mean it will just go through fruits. It's going through all child objects of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach($xml->fruits->item as $item) {
    //$item has to be cast to a string otherwise it will be a SimpleXML element
    $foodlist[] = (string) $item;
}
print_r($foodlist);
```

I think this should give you what you're looking for, an array containing the text value of each of the item nodes that are children of the fruits node.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a bunch to everyone. This simple exercise has taught me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code. It works fine for me.
Another thing - it might be that you described it wrong, or might be that you understand this wrong. $foodlist should contain array of SimpleXML element objects (in your case "`<fruits>`" and "`<vegetables>`"), not array of fruits. If you want get only fruits you should access `$xml->fruits->item;`.

Edit: 
if you want to build an array of fruits try this:

```
$array = (array)$xml->fruits;
print_r($array['item']); // Should dipslay list of fruits

//or this
foreach ($xml->fruits->item as $fruit){
  $array2[] = (string) $fruit; //typecast to string, because $fruit is xml element object.
}
print_r($array2); // Should dipslay list of fruits
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think we're close. I basically want my final array ($foodlist) to be identical to what it would be had I used this command: `$foodlist = array("Apple","Orange","Banana");`. I just want it to be a straight array, devoid of any reference to the originating XML. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can typecast `$xml->fruits` object to array (`$array = (array) $xml->fruits;`. Your fruits will be in `$array['item']`. Also you can try this `foreach ($xml->fruits->item as $fruit){
  $array[] = (string) $fruit; //typecast to string, because $fruit is xml element object.
}`Thats the closest thing I can get without researching more into simpleXML. :)

Comment: Wasn't abble to add proper formating to comment, so edited my answer and put there the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `foreach( $xml['data'] as $fruits=>$item )`

---- edit ----

```
foreach( $xml as $fruits => $item ) {
    if( $fruits == "fruits" )
        $foodlist[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: That would go through the vegetables too.

Comment: Thanks for that edit, but it still returns a fairly confusing looking array when I print_r (with references to SimpleXML). Please see my comment to egis's answer for an idea of what I need. Apologies for my unclear description in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Is this it ? http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Looks promising - I'll give it a whirl. Thanks.